# SQL Server 2008 Error 233

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating new login in SQL Server 2008 with following sql script:

```
CREATE LOGIN [xyz] WITH PASSWORD='xyz',
            DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
            CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

It creates new login successfully. But when I try to login with it using SQL Server Management Studio it fails saying:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

What's wrong? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: There is also more (duplicated?) discussion of this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/

Answer (score 37):

Here is how I done it, maybe it works for you too.

1. login Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with windows authentication.
2. right-click onto the server name in Object Explorer and click Properties
3. In the new tab click Security
4. select SQL Server and Windows Authentication
5. Ok
6. Close the SQL server management studio.
7. start+run
8. write services.msc
9. search for SQL there and restart all services.

that works for me.

Comment: Great answer, I had the same problem so I enabled mixed connections, but only restarting the services made it actually work. Thanks.

Comment: best answer, I spent hours trying multiple solutions until I found this correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, the better one. Even worked with SQL Server 17/18.

Answer (score 12):

It's also possible that you're trying to use SQL Server Authentication without having enabled it.  To fix this, right-click Properties on your server instance in SQL Server Management Studio, and update the security settings to include "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. You will most likely have to restart your SQL server after updating the setting.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to connect using named pipes, but SQL Server is not listening on that protocol.  [See MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496.aspx)

The two fixes MSDN suggests are:

- Connect using TCP/IP, or use the SQL
  Server Configuration Manager to
  enable remote connections using named
  pipes.
- Using SQL Server Configuration
  Manager on the client computer, move
  TCP before named pipes in the
  protocol order list.

Comment: To change the order: Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Native Client Configuration -> (RMB) Client Protocols -> Properties -> (Move the Enabled Protocols up or down).  Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: 
1. log in as the master user or windows authenticated user.
2. right click on the database --> properties --> security --> 
3. change  Windows Authentication mode to "SQL server and windows authentication mode" by clicking on the radio button. (if it is not)
4. restart the server

Comment: This is literally what the top 2 answers have said.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i first setup SQL Server 2014 on my local machine.
In my case the solution was to set a correct defualt database.

Answer (score 0):

Login with Administrator in SQL Server
Go to Securities >> Logins >> select your user name and go to properties

From Status >> uncheck user account lock check box
Change password for the user
Restart the sql server and login with your username.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error.
I've resolved the error by following below mentioned steps:

1. Disable named pipes and restart sql services.
2. After restart sql server I enabled names pipes and did a sql server restart again ([Link for Step 1 and 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1177161.aspx?A+connection+was+successfully+established+with+the+server+but+then+an+error+occurred+during+the+pre+login+handshake+))
3. Connect to SQL server via studio.
4. Right click on SQL instance --> Properties --> Connections --> "Set the Maximum number of 5. concurrent connections to '0' ".
5. Save the change.
6. Restart the SQL server if possible. ([Link for step 3 to 6](http://learn-n-joy.blogspot.in/2013/01/a-connection-was-successfully.html))

I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

This is might not be a connection issue . Check your default database and if that is online . More commonly this issues seen when the default database will be offline or not exists . If your default database other than master ,better check this option.

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to go around the problem.

- Open one instance and login using the windows authentication
- allow sql and windows auth both by right cliking on the db server.
- Open second instance and login using sql authentication.

bingo the sql authenticated instance open .. :)

Actually in this way we cheat the sql authenticated instance as it tries to find an already running instance.. worked fr me.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the solution but was not able to solve it until I found [this URL](https://www.windowstechupdates.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-233-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe/) which says to do the following:

Open SQL Server Management Studio and run the these queries:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
go
reconfigure
go
sp_configure 'user connections', 0
go
reconfigure
go
```

The reason why we got this error is that the user connections was reset to 1, so only one user was able to connect with the SQL server.
just a simple query worked for. I hope this will work for others as well.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the script style, but login through GUI I encountered the same error code. I had entered wrong `user name` and this is why I was getting the `Sql Server, Error: 233`.
 In order to resolve this, you should input the following information:

Server Name: `MachineName\SQLEXPRESS` 
Authentication: `SqlServer Authentication` 
User Name: `Assigned user-name` or simply `sa`
Password: `xyzpqr`

NOTE: Here I have wrote above data for demo purpose only, actual data is your machine & software's properties.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326280.aspx

Go to --> Remot setting

Go to "Remote" tab

in "Remote Assistance", Tick "**Allow Remote Assistance connection to this computer**", Click the "Advance" button and tick the "**Allow...**" and in the "Invitation" set the "**30 days**"

Then  in the "Remote Desktop" part

Just tick "**Allow remote connection to this computer**"

Answer (score 0):

After following the examples here and still not getting in, I found that my sa login was disabled. The following got me in:

```
Logged back in under windows authentication.  
Expanded Security Tab 
Expanded Logins Tab 
Right-clicked sa and selected Properties
Went to the Status Tab
Under Login: Clicked 'Enabled' radio
Restarted Server and logged in as sa.
This assumes you have set sa password already using
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process."

I was getting this problem from sqllocaldb when used from within Docker.  The problem was the Docker image was not allocated enough memory.  Increasing the memory actually fixed the problem.