# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (Error Number: 233)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having error while connecting to SQL Server:

[image]

Details in Stack Trace are:

```
===================================

Cannot connect to ServerName.

===================================

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: ServerName
Error Number: 233
Severity: 20
State: 0


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

**NOTE** **I have tried**

- closing, reopening Sql server Management Studio.
- closing , reopen VS & rebuild Solution
- killed worker process accessing database.
- login credentials are correct.
- able to ping server to make sure its not down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Error 233](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072505/sql-server-2008-error-233)

Comment: Check whether all your SQL Services are running. If yes, still restart all once and check again. Also, check whether MIxed authentication mode enabled for your SQL server.

Comment: I have enabled and started the browser service and the issue resolved. Please try.

Comment: My server is running in Mixed mode, I've stopped and started it and I'm still getting this error :-(.  I'm getting this from SQL localdb specifically.

Comment: same problem happened to me and changing the DNS to the google DNS (8.8.8.8) fixed it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Turn out to be some SQL service was stopped somehow on server. Restarting SQL Server service manually was the solution.

Comment: Use Sql Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services to find out what processes are running (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc)

Answer (score 224):

#### Same Error with Connection String in Visual Studio dev environment

Our development database server was recently given a self-signed certificate so it automatically became untrusted. This resulted in the login error cited above. I added `TrustServerCertificate=True` to my connection string and it works now.

`"Server=TheServerAddress; Database=TheDataBase; User Id=TheUsername; Password=ThePassword; TrustServerCertificate=True"`

NOTE: This certificate configuration is not recommended for production environments.

Comment: This fixed it for me. It appears to be a breaking change in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 2. See https://erikej.github.io/sqlclient/efcore/2020/06/22/sqlclient-2-breaking-changes.html

Comment: This also fixed it for me and I found it mentioned in the [release notes](https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/main/docs/releases/1.5.0/#yessql-breaking-changes) of OrchardCore 1.5.0.

Answer (score 115):

For SQL2008,

- open **Management Studio**
- Rt click on **instance**
- go to **properties**
- select **Security**
- Under **Server Authentication**, check **SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode**
- hit **OK**

Restart the server using configuration manager.

Answer (score 51):

This is what helped me [[src]](https://blog.greglow.com/2020/01/16/sql-sql-server-the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted/):

File > Connect Object Explorer... > Options (bottom right) > Connection properties tab > Trust Server Certificate tickbox

[image]

Comment: This also works in Azure Data Studio (including macOS)

Comment: In my case I checked the checkbox of trusted certificate under Visual Studio 22.

Answer (score 36):

In my case I had the following by mistake in my connection string:

```
Encrypt=True
```

Changing to

```
Encrypt=False
```

Solved the problem

```
"Server=***;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=False;User  ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Comment: +1 This seems to be the new norm for .Net Core 7.  Was working fine yesterday before updating, but today failed until this was added.

Comment: It works fine but I think it's a better idea to add TrustServerCertificate=True instead of disabling encryption by adding Encrypt=False.

Comment: down voted because disabling encryption may be against many companies policies, and at the least is against best practice.

Answer (score 28):

For me, adding **Trusted_Connection=True** to the connection string helped.

Answer (score 25):

the following points work for me. Try:

1. start SSMS as administrator
2. make sure SQL services are running. Change startup type to 'Automatic'

[image]

3. In SSMS, in service instance property table, enable below:

[image]

Comment: Where the heck was the first screenshot taken?

Comment: it is under the Task Manager > Services tab

Answer (score 15):

I solved it using this parametres
`Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True`

If you have a problem, update OLEDB Driver 18.6.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

For MS SQL Management Studio

On the connection window, select Options and then the Connection Properties tab, and check the "Trust Server Certificate" option:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also get this error, somewhat unhelpfully, if the database name specified in the connection string doesn't exist. Check your Db Name carefully!

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/9225/sql-server-a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-b):

> **Root Cause:** Maximum connection has been exceeded on your SQL Server Instance.
>
> How to fix it...!
>
> 1. F8 or Object Explorer
> 2. Right click on Instance --> Click Properties...
> 3. Select "Connections" on "Select a page" area on left
> 4. Change the value to 0 (Zero) for "Maximum number of concurrent connections(0 = Unlimited)"
> 5. Restart the SQL Server Instance once.

Apart from that also ensure that below are enabled:

- Shared Memory protocol is enabled
- Named Pipes protocol is enabled
- TCP/IP is enabled

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if you cannot login Object Explorer will not show the instance of the server

Comment: I'm having trouble starting SQL Server Agent to try that.  It wont' start for me.'

Comment: This was my issue (Azure Sql Server). I was processing a queue with hundreds of messages all arriving at once.  Resolved by slowing the queue down to process 5 at a time.

Answer (score 3):

When you starting application 'Run as administrator'.This way I avoided this error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Steps to resolve the issue:

1. Goto File > Connect Object Explorer.. > Options > Connection Properties: Make sure 'Trust connection certificate' checkbox is checked.
2. Goto File > Connect Object Explorer.. > Options > Connection Properties: Make sure 'Encrypt connection' check box is unchecked.
3. Check whether 'SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)' and 'SQL Server Agent(MSSQLSERVER)' services are running.
4. Add the following statements in the connection string:

   Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;

This way, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2016 solution/workaround here (could also work in earlier versions).  This may not work or be appropriate in every situation, but I resolved the error by granting my database user read/write schema ownership as follows in SSMS:

Database > Security > Users > User > Properties > Owned Schemas > check **db_datareader** and **db_datawriter**.

Comment: Mine just won't let me do it.  Says I cannot use special principal dbo.

Answer (score 1):

My problem resolved by this what changes i have done in .net core
Do this changes in
**Appsetting.json**

```
Server=***;Database=***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***; Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30
```

and
**Do following changes in Package console manager**

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=***;Database=***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***; Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context DatabaseContext -f
```

*Happy coding*

Comment: But I'm trying to use Windows Auth.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

Go to SQL Server Management, Disable Memory Shared, TCP/IP and Pipes named.

Restart the server and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing <default> to master under Connection Properties in Options
solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source of this problem is if the database login is not mapped to a  user in the database. Solution is of course simple, map the login to the database user.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I had a unique situation - other than all the answers posted here.

I connect to the database with a restricted login (mapped to the database user) **and NOT the sysadmin sa**

Now I restored by database from a copy of another database on the same sql server database (same issue would occur even if you have restored form another sql server database server), but missed to delete the database user and recreated it.

So, essentially, if you are restoring your sql server database here is what you need to do:

1. Restore the database
2. Delete any roles owned by the user (that is ultimately mapped to the login which is not working)
3. Delete the user mapped to the login
4. Re-map the login to the user
5. Recreate the role and add the user to that role
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes specifying the database (instead of default) solves this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error message in code line containing `SqlConnection.Open()` running my .NET code as x64 application. Running as x86 causing no errors.

Solution was to deactivate the `Force protocol encryption` option for TCP/IP in 
`%windir%\System32\cliconfg.exe`

[Force protocol encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BeMZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error because the user trying to login was lacking permissions.

I don't recommend doing this, but I fixed it by granting the user `db_owner` globally. It was a local instance, so not a huge security concern.

Answer (score 0):

To add on top of @Pranav Singh and @Rahul Tripathi answer.
After doing all the mentioned by those 2 users, my .net app still wasnt connecting to the database. My solution was.

Open Sql Server Configuration Manager, go to Network configuration of SQL SERVER, click on protocols, right click on TCP/IP and select enabled.
I also right clicked on it opened properties, Ip directions, and scrolled to the bottom (IPAII , and there in TCP Port, I did setup a port (1433 is supposed to be default))

Answer (score 0):

I had previously limited the number of connections to my DB to 2.
Clearly this was an issue.
After restarting the server, login, you will get an error popup and just click OK.
Right click on the server in the object explorer, go to properties, go to connection and change your limited number of connections (I went from 2 to 20) everything works fine now.

I appreciate this is an old post. But I came across it today, saw lots on MS forums which were incorrect solutions. Almost all of them on here didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is deleting .ldf files from \bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

Got this error from downloading Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package

removed **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** package and it worked.

Comment: I got it working doing the reverse. By removing System.Data.SqlClient and adding the newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following did the trick:

- Open SQL Server Configuration
- On the left under "SQL Server Network Configuration", click on "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER"
- Then on the right make sure to set "Named Pipes" to Enabled

Restarted my pc. Then could succesfully login again with my sa account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party with this, but I found when I saw this error it was due to the login I was using not having permission to the stored procedure it was trying to execute.

Answer (score -1):

I had to do 2 things: Do what Joseph Wu said and change the authentication to be SQL and Windows. But I also had to go to Server Properties > Advanced and change "Enable Contained Databases" to True.

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions above gave me a clue.
The sa account was generating this exact error.
I was able to log in with a Windows service account with admin privileges.
At some point recently a GPO had been applied to strengthen the password policy.
The existing sa password didn't meet the new strengthened password policy.

Log into SQL Server Management Studio with alternative admin credentials.
Instance > Security > Logins > account (sa in my case)
Untick "Enforce password policy" Click OK.
Disconnect and login again with the account.

Worked for me.

HAd to reboot the server to get various jobs running again but if I took time to go through them I probably could have restarted them from the SSMS without a server restart.

Comment: If there is an password policy to strengthen password, please change password according to policy and don't disable policy. It will work but will make your application susceptible to hacks & less secure.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Create the User in Security.
Default database will be set to Master
After that, you can log in to SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score -1):

i got the error after deleting a database. this db was the default db chosen by the mssql management tool. so, the connection was established but because the db was missing, the process resulted in an error. the solution is to change the defaut db to a db that exists.
in the connection popup press the 'options' button, and then in the 'connect to database' field, choose one that exists in your sql server. that solved the problem for me. :)

Answer (score -1):

*SO warns me that I had to review all previous 30+ answers - I did and I am pretty sure my case is different.*

My reason was that I was connecting to MSSQL 2019 using password and my **password was lost** and was specified as **Password=;** in the .net connection string.

And it really looks like a bug in MSSQL. If I specify any other invalid password the error is "Login failed for user X". And what is really strange is that if I specify blank password again (after specifying non-blank invalid password) the error is "Login failed for user X" again. Not that strange one about "connection established" and so on.