# Error connecting to SQL Server 2012 with VB.NET 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to fix a project which already use a 100% connections to Oracle. They are trying to upgrade the project to start using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. But I'm having issues connecting to the database. We use Windows authentication.

I can login fine directly to SQL Server 2012 using Management Studio and Windows authentication. If I create a fresh new `WindowsApplication1` project to test the connection code it works fine, I'm using this code (and get an error is at `conn.Open()`):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Open_Filing_Image
    'Create ADO.NET objects.
    Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private myReader As SqlDataReader
    Private results As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create a Connection object.
    Dim connStr As [String] = "Server=servername; Database=dbname; Integrated Security=True"
    myConn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
    'Create a Command object.
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DdocName FROM dbo.Document WHERE XAlaskaID = '72010' and DdocType = 'Filings'"
    'Open the connection.
    Try
        myConn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Concatenate the query result into a string.
    Do While myReader.Read()
        results = myReader.GetValue(0)
    Loop
    'Display results.
    Dim documentID As String = results
    Dim outPath As String = "http://address.internet`enter code here`/" + documentID + (".pdf")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outPath)
    'Close the reader and the database connection.
    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified data could not be decrypted.

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem-statement is contradictory. You said "If I create a fresh new WindowsApplication1 Project to test the connection code it works fine" but then describe an error message.

Comment: Also the same issue is reported elsewhere with several possible causes and solutions, are you certain none of these apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ

Comment: Yes, I test my conde with any VS 2010, 2013 and 2015 and works the connection, I can pull sqlcommand and sqlreader fine. But im working on a project that already was build by old programmers written in vb.net 2010 and all connections is based on oracle. im just trying to make a simple connection to test, but that is the message I get.

Comment: Please post your connection code from the project that doesn't work. Your `Form1` code is not relevant here.

Comment: I edit my original post, sorry first time in here. Also I check your link and nothing of that worked for me.

Comment: Try adding "Encrypt=yes;" to your connection string.  If that doesn't work, try switching it to "no".

Comment: when using Encrypt=yes in my connection string I get: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) If I use Encrypt=No I get: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified data could not be decrypted.
)

Comment: You are missing the Provider. Add this to your connection string (assumes SQL Server 2012):  `Provider=SQLNCLI11;`

Comment: I tried using that `Provider=SQLNCLI11` and it says provider not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it doing some research and some assistance by another programmer:

The project had a Bcrypt reference that block the connections to SQL. I delete all Bcrypt and add transport credentials to Windows in the app.config. any way thanks guys.

Comment: Use the edit link in your question. Don't post anything as an answer, unless it is the answer to your question.