# Not able to Connect to MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have recently migrated our server. Now I am try to connect to `MSSQL Servers` through the Administrator account but I am getting the below error.

I am trying to connect with `SQL Server Auth`.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

PS: Below are things, I have already tried:

1. Restart the services.
2. Check the order of protocols & make sure -
   Shared Memory> TCP/IP > then Named Pipes
3. Also, I have tried to use
   with a fully qualified name.

I don't have access to connect with `Windows Auth`. I have tried to create an account but no luck. Will you advise on how to hack in now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (Error Number: 233)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)

Comment: Thanks but I did read and try all of these. The problem I am not able to connect SQL Servers at all, so will not able to see to the instance & go properties etc.?

Comment: How are you doing authentication? How did you migrate the accounts?

Comment: We have migrate it through Vmotion (v2v) migration, so there is no issues. Even i have started the DB and Application from services, it running fine now. All application test and working properly. The problem, seem we don't have SQL AUTH enabled so we didn't have created our id for window authentication. We are authenticated through AD/account.

Answer (score 0):

The user id I had in my connection string was not existing in the database (not server).