# SQL Server: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, .net-core

Our application sometimes throws out this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
>   successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
>   during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (10054): An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The application runs perfectly fine for some time, but just sometimes throws the exception above. Until now it is pretty hard to find the cause of this. Some say that it has to do with the amount of connections, but we have it set at zero and therefor it should be maximized at around 32k connections which we think we do not use.

EDIT: Seen the SSL provider is used and the client OS version is lower than the SQL server OS version I am thinking about the TLS version or cipher suite. I still cannot figure out why the same client is sometimes using a different/incompatible cipher suite or TLS version.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server's logs?

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing in there. I am thinking in the direction of TLS versions or cipher suites, but I am far from sure.

Comment: You might want look to look at the following article at Microsoft: [Applications experience "forcibly closed" TLS connection errors when connecting SQL Servers in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4557473/errors-when-applications-try-to-connect-to-sql-server-in-windows). This issue reappeared with a recent update, it might shed a light on how the cipher suites work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (Error Number: 233)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)

Comment: Kees: You should mark @nimajv's answer as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155515/109941

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience when my source os version was windows server 2016 and destination os was windows 2012, after windows update it happened, check windows recent updates.