# EF Scaffold-DbContext - Login failed for user ' '. (empty ' ')

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to use Scaffold-DbContext but I got error:

> Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=Test Trusted_Connection=True'
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Connection string in another app:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "AppConnection": "Server=serverName;database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Error (scaffolding):

> Login failed for user ''.

I dont have user in db and I connect by the same connectionstring to this base in another application and it works but not anymore with Scaffold-DbContext.

I tried to use:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

[A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (Error Number: 233)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/49451319/dotnet-ef-scaffold-login-fails-for-user-sa-on-a-sqlserver-macos-linux

Answer (score 1):

I guess that because you haven't explicitly specified `Windows Authentication` then it tries to use Username and Password which are null.

Add `Integrated Security=SSPI` to your `connection string` that uses `Windows Authentication` explicitly.

If it didn't work, feedback me to provide another solution.

Comment: @Xia are you using IIS? can you take a screenshot from database->security->login list of users?